# 'Script error' fix does not work for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cors

[The fix](https://blog.sentry.io/2016/05/17/what-is-script-error.html) for the cryptic JS `Script error` (resulting from errors in a cross-origin script) is well documented. I've implemented the solution and it now works for Firefox, but it does not for Chrome. Has anyone else encountered this problem or know what might be going wrong? I did look through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122766/cryptic-script-error-is-still-not-fixed-with-cors), where they identify it as a bug that was fixed back in 2013, so I'm not sure what gives.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, which might not be your issue, but in case someone else comes here with the same thing:

Adding the CORS headers to the HTTP responses for the linked status is not enough.  I overlooked this, but adding `crossorigin="anonymous"` (or `crossorigin="use-credentials` see [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes) ) to the `<script...` tag is also necessary.

It makes sense - in order to allow sharing of source code info in between two domains, one would want permissions to be given on *both* sides - the page requesting the external script, and the source of the script both have to be okay with showing debug info.

It's already in the "The Fix" link in the original post, but I lost some time to it, so thought it was worth reiterating.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and I don't know if this helps you (probably not since it's been over a year), but for any future readers: send your files over HTTPS, not just HTTP. It seems that Chrome is stricter than Firefox and won't allow this 'fix' to work over regular HTTP.

(And if you're using webpack, be sure to have `devtool: "source-map"` set (as opposed to `eval-source-map`)